# struggling to create an object a, create a collection of B add the collection to A

Tags: vba, collections

Using VBA I am trying to create a simple object model and struggling to understand the failure.  I get no errors.

Here is the scenario:
I create a house object
then a room object, then a collection of rooms called myrooms.  each has gone well and stands inspection.
The house object has a property called rooms of type rooms
Both objects exist without errors.
In house I have . . .

```
private pRooms as rooms
 Property Let rooms(rm  As rooms)
   set pRooms = rm
 End Property
Property get rooms( )
  set rooms =pRooms 
End Property
```

in my code I write 
     set House.rooms = myRooms (myRooms is a valid collection I can inspect)

Then I look at House in a watch window and .rooms  is Nothing

What am I doing worng?

Answer (score 0):

Since rooms is a collection, it is an object. You should use property Set instead of property let

p.s. I am surprised that your code does not generate an error.
And BTW, why do you give the property the same name of an existing class? dont look for trouble, i suggest you rename your collection into something like roomCollection.

```
   Private prooms as RoomCollection
   Public Property Set rooms(Byref rm  As RoomCollection)
       Set pRooms = rm
    End Property
```